# how to use ng-model value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and having difficulty in using **ng-repeat** with **ng-model**.

My html code is somewhat like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="no_of_sets" placeholder="number of sets" name="no_of_sets">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<div ng-repeat="a in range(no_of_sets) track by $index">{{no_of_sets}}</div>
```

and my controller code is like this:

```
$scope.range=function(no) {
    return new Array(no); 
};
```

*I want the user to enter a number in the textbox and print his number that many times.*

But this code doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: this appears to be working as intended, though not the logic you are expecting.  `new Array(no);` isn't going to create an array with `no` elements, it is going to create a new array of one element of value `no`.

Comment: Try changing `return new Array(no);` to `return new Array(parseInt(no));` Or set the field type to `type="number"`

Comment: @Claies using a constant number in place of *no_of_sets* in ng-repeat seems to be working fine. Though it is using the function *range*.

Comment: right, but as @AlonEitan has pointed out, `no_of_sets` is a string, not an int, thus the `new Array()` call is creating a single element array.  Supplying an int instead (via `parseInt()`) fixes this, though you may have issues when the textbox is empty or is value `0`.

Comment: @AlonEitan after changing to `return new Array(parseInt(no));` seems to give RangeError: Invalid array length error. how can i fix it?

Comment: the `new Array()` constructor function operates differently depending on the type of the arguments supplied to it.  It is therefore recommended to not use this unless absolutely necessary, as it produces confusing output.

Comment: right, this is what I was mentioning, if the textbox is empty or `0`, then you will get a `RangeError`.

Comment: @jAYANTYADAV I think adding `$scope.no_of_sets = 1;` or any other default number might solve this, you should validate the input before creating the array

Comment: Change input type to number, problem solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening in your code: The function that creates an array will just give you undefined same number of times as the value entered by the user. You need an array with that number repeated that number of times only.

For that you can do something like this:

```
    <form ng-submit="createArray()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="no_of_sets" placeholder="number of sets" name="no_of_sets">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="a in arr track by $index">{{no_of_sets}}</div>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.createArray = function(){

        $scope.arr = [];

        for (var i=0; i< $scope.no_of_sets; i++){
            $scope.arr.push($scope.no_of_sets);
        };

    };
```

Comment: @GeorgeLee no doubt this is working fine. Is there some other way to directly use the value in ng-model to run my n-repeat?

Comment: of course you can, do this `<div ng-repeat="a in range(no_of_sets) track by $index">{{no_of_sets}}</div>` then `$scope.range = function(number){

        var tempArray = [];

        for (var i=0; i< number; i++){
            tempArray.push($scope.no_of_sets);
        };
        return tempArray;
    };`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're passing a string to the function range().
Simply changing your input type to number will do the trick!

```
<input type="text" ... />
```

change to

```
<input type="number" ... />
```

See working example in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lLdZi9JdR5ExbyjtKJcx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `range` function to this:

```
$scope.range = function(no) {
    var n = parseInt(no);
    return new Array(isNaN(n) ? 0 : n);
};
```

Your mistake is that you pass a `string` to the `Array()`, which creates a new array with the single element (the passed string). To create an array of a certain length you should pass a number to it.

Answer (score 0):

use custom `range filter`

```
<input type="number" ng-model="no_of_sets">
<div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:no_of_sets" >{{no_of_sets}}
</div>

angular.module('sampleApp', [])
  .filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);

    for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }

    return input;
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/u0e67n6k/